# setState updating a mounted state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

While writing out Conway's Game of Life, I'm getting an error where the state's not actually being updated. I get a warning that `setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.` but everything I've tried so far to get rid of that hasn't helped. You can find my App Component below:

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        board: [],
        rows: 50,
        cols: 50,
        cycles: 0
    }
    this.createBoard();
}

createBoard() {
    var newBoard = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.rows; i++) {
        var row = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < this.state.cols; j++) {
            let fillValue;
            if (Math.random() > 0.65) {
                fillValue = true;
            } else {
                fillValue = false;
            }
            row.push(fillValue);
        }
        newBoard.push(row);
    }
    console.log(newBoard);
    this.setState({board: newBoard});
}

render() {
    return(
        <div id="root">
            <h1>Conway's Game of Life</h1>
            <Controller />
            {console.log(this.state.board)}
            <Board
                board={this.state.board}
                rows={this.state.rows}
                cols={this.state.cols}
            />
            <p>Years Passed: {this.state.cycles}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

The issue is with the setState at the end of the `createBoard()` function. The `console.log` above the setState prints out fine, but the other one in the render method prints out an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing the place where you have called the createBoard() method fixes this error.Instead of calling method is constructor I moved it to componentDidMount Please note that your two components **Board** & **Controller** are missing in the code so I've commented them out

Here is the code

```js
class TestJS extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            board: [],
            rows: 50,
            cols: 50,
            cycles: 0
        };
        this.createBoard = this.createBoard.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.createBoard();
    }

    createBoard() {
        var newBoard = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.rows; i++) {
            var row = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < this.state.cols; j++) {
                let fillValue;
                if (Math.random() > 0.65) {
                    fillValue = true;
                } else {
                    fillValue = false;
                }
                row.push(fillValue);
            }
            newBoard.push(row);
        }
        console.log(newBoard);
        this.setState({board: newBoard});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id="root">
                <h1>Conway's Game of Life</h1>
                {console.log(this.state.board)}
                <p>Years Passed: {this.state.cycles}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TestJS;
```

Comment: I think `componentDidMount` is a better option in this case.

Comment: componentDidMount also ok. we can use componentDidMount or componentWillMount Based on our requirements.

Answer (score 1):

It's exactly what the error says. You're setting state on an unmounted component. **The component is not yet mounted when the constructor is called**.
Do it inside `componentDidMount()` life cycle function:

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        board: [],
        rows: 50,
        cols: 50,
        cycles: 0
    };
    this.createBoard = this.createBoard.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.createBoard();
}

createBoard() {
    var newBoard = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.rows; i++) {
        var row = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < this.state.cols; j++) {
            let fillValue;
            if (Math.random() > 0.65) {
                fillValue = true;
            } else {
                fillValue = false;
            }
            row.push(fillValue);
        }
        newBoard.push(row);
    }
    console.log(newBoard);
    this.setState({board: newBoard});
}

render() {
    return(
        <div id="root">
            <h1>Conway's Game of Life</h1>
            <Controller />
            {console.log(this.state.board)}
            <Board
                board={this.state.board}
                rows={this.state.rows}
                cols={this.state.cols}
            />
            <p>Years Passed: {this.state.cycles}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Please take a look at [Lifecycle methods](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/life_cycle/introduction.html).